# Regex in .vimrc throwing "Not an editor command"

Tags: vim

I am trying to create a keybinding to delete all the commented lines in the file.

The following gives me the desirable result `:g/^\(#\|$\)/d`

I am declaring the binding as following in `~/.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <leader>dcl :g/\v^(#|$)/d<cr>
```

It is throwing the following error:

```
E492: Not an editor command: $)/d<cr>
```

What is the proper way to declare a keybinding with regex?

Comment: escape the | with \

Comment: See `:h map-bar`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace your binding by:

```
nnoremap <leader>dcl :g/\v^(#<bar>$)/d<cr>
```

Indeed, in scripts or in the command line, vim considers `|` characters as a command delimiter; so you have to replace it by `<bar>`.

Comment: "vim considers `|` characters as a command delimiter" ...except when it doesn't. `:help :bar`, `:help :command-bar`. ;) (Just a nitpick for those who want to know more; your answer is perfectly fine!)